# Neural network has different output shape that target data

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have simple neural network where I'm trying to predict regression problem:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5, 41))
network = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
network = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(24, return_sequences=True)(network)
network = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8)(network)
network = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear')(network)
```

what gives appropriate summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         [(None, 5, 41)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_15 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 32)             9472      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_16 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 24)             5472      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_17 (LSTM)               (None, 8)                 1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 18        
=================================================================
Total params: 16,018
Trainable params: 16,018
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The output shape of this neural network is `(1, 2)`, but my label data shape is `(2, 1, 1)`.

As You can see this is incompatible, but it still trains and predicts:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history = model.fit(windows.train, epochs=5, shuffle=True, validation_data=windows.val)

Epoch 1/5
678/678 [==============================] - 14s 15ms/step - loss: 0.0317 - val_loss: 0.0465
Epoch 2/5
678/678 [==============================] - 9s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0260 - val_loss: 0.0636
Epoch 3/5
678/678 [==============================] - 9s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0217 - val_loss: 0.0387
```

The question is **why is it work? Should it give some error?**

windows.train output:

```
Inputs shape (batch, time, features): (2, 5, 41)
Labels shape (batch, time, features): (2, 1, 1)
```

I'm using tensorflow-2.6

Comment: Output would have shape `(batch_size, units)`. Output of Dense layer (None,2). This is expected behaviour. There is no mismatch in output shape and label data shape. Thanks!

Comment: But if my label data is `(2, 1, 1)` should it give some error?